# Rails: Installing font-awesome in Rails 6.0.0-rc1 with webpacker and yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install FontAwesome via `yarn` by doing `yarn add @fontawesome/fontawesome-free`, and then adding it to my `application.scss`:

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/webfonts';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/scss/fa-solid';
```

I have tried several things to write in the `application.scss` that I've seen through the internet, but none of them works, as I get the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#index
Showing /Users/foo/dev/project/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: ~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/scss/fontawesome.
Load paths:
  /Users/foo/dev/project/app/assets/images
  /Users/foo/dev/project/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/foo/dev/project/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/foo/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/coffee-rails-5.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/foo/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actioncable-6.0.0.rc1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/foo/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-6.0.0.rc1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/foo/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionview-6.0.0.rc1/lib/assets/compiled
  /Users/foo/dev/project/node_modules
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `yarn add @fontawesome/fontawesome-free` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remove the `~` sign at the start of your imports and it should work fine.

It should be something like this:

```
$fa-font-path: '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/webfonts';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/scss/fontawesome';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/scss/fa-solid';
```

Answer (score 22):

As of November 2019 I have found this the easiest way to get it all working:

Install via Yarn:

`yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

Import in your `application.js` file:

`import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";`

Pretty straightforward and worked for me!

Comment: For those with PRO accounts, just change `free` to `pro`. Just like: `import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css";`

Answer (score 10):

[Asim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8551976/asim-hashmi) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55992073/5573177) put me on the right track. However, it seems like some of the import paths have changed for the newer version (5.8.2) of FontAwesome. Here is what I needed to put inside of my `application.scss` file to make FontAwesome 5.8.2 available for use in my Rails 6.0.0-rc1 application:

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';

@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
```

Comment: Nope. I can omit the `~` from the two imports, and everything still works. Removing the `~` from the `$fa-font-path` declaration causes webpacker to die with a module resolution error. However, omitting the `~` from the imports causes RubyMine to complain and lose the ability to get code insights and jump to definition.

Answer (score 7):

Let Webpacker handle everything for you. Import the `fontawesome.scss` directly into your `application.js` file. 
Webpack will copy the font and reference it correctly.

```
$ yarn add --dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

```
// app/javascript/src/font-awesome.js
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
```

```
// app/javascript/packs/application.js
// Other imports left out for brevity
import '../src/font-awesome.js';
```

```html
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag "application" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

I installed **Font-awesome** in a **Rails 6** application that I was working on this way:

Firstly, install the free version of the **font-awesome** package in the application:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Then, run the rails webpacker to install any other dependencies:

```
rails webpacker:install
```

Next, import font-awesome stylesheets to your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file:

```
$fa-font-path: '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims';
```

**Note**: If you're wondering how the location of these files was gotten, check your the `node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free` directory in your application.

And then, require the Javascript file in your `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file:

```
require("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free");
```

Finally, ensure that your stylesheet and javascript header links in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file remain like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

After a long weekend I could finally find a answer: Font Awesome could not find the font files due to Rails assets digest addition on file names.

In order to fix it, you need to overwrite the font-face.

The magic lives in the `asset-url` helper used to find the files.

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free

cat >> app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss << \HERE_DOC
// node_modules
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
// plugins
@import 'plugins/font-awesome-font-face'
HERE_DOC

# copy @font-face definition from node_modules...all.css and replace url with asset-url
cat >> app/assets/stylesheets/plugins/font-awersome-font-face.css' << HERE_DOC
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
  src: asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2") format("woff2"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff") format("woff"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf") format("truetype"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot");
  src: asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot");
  src: asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), asset-url("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg");
}
HERE_DOC
```

Source: https://blog.trk.in.rs/2014/07/01/ruby-on-rails-layouts-and-rendering/#fontawesome